# Cannot see action buttons even notification by sending push via NodeJS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I cannot see notification actions even push notification alert too with sending below nodeJS. There is no issue about sending simple alert from same nodeJS configurations like this:

```
notification.alert = 'Hello World \u270C';
```

I see local scheduled notification's alert actions with:

```
self.scheduleNotification(event: "test", interval: 3)
```

It would be great to know what I'm doing wrong on **notification payload** side.

**AppDelegate.swift** file:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (status: Bool, error: Error?) in
            if error == nil {
                self.registerCategory()
                // Now, I can see action buttons for that scheduled notification, but not from payload (nodeJS)
                self.scheduleNotification(event: "test", interval: 3)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
                print("Push registration success.")
            }
            else {
                print("Push registration failed:")
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func registerCategory() -> Void {

        let acceptAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ACCEPT_ACTION",
                                                title: "Accept",
                                                options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let declineAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "DECLINE_ACTION",
                                                 title: "Decline",
                                                 options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))

        let category : UNNotificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory.init(identifier: "MEETING_INVITATION", actions: [acceptAction, declineAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.setNotificationCategories([category])

    }

    func scheduleNotification (event : String, interval: TimeInterval) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        content.title = event
        content.body = "body"
        content.categoryIdentifier = "MEETING_INVITATION"
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)
        let identifier = "id_" + event
        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        })
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("Handled deviceToken: ")
        print(token)
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }
}
```

**app.js** file:

```
var apn = require('apn')
var util = require('util')

// Set up apn with the APNs Auth Key:
var apnProvider = new apn.Provider({  
     token: {
        key: '____', // Path to the key p8 file
        keyId: '____', // The Key ID of the p8 file (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/key)
        teamId: '____', // The Team ID of your Apple Developer Account (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/)
    },
    production: false // Set to true if sending a notification to a production iOS app
});

// Enter the device token from the Xcode console:
var deviceToken = '____';

// Prepare a new notification:
var notification = new apn.Notification();

// Bundle ID:
notification.topic = '____'; 

// It works:
notification.category = "MEETING_INVITATION";
notification.alert = {"title":"React with push","body":"Tap to see actions about that push."};

// It doesn't work:
// notification.payload = {"aps":{"category":"MEETING_INVITATION","alert":{"title":"React with push","body":"Tap to see actions about that push."}}};

apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then(function(result) {  
    // Check the result for any failed devices
    console.log(util.inspect(result, true, 7, true));
});
```

Comment: Do you get the notification to the device at all? Even without the actions, but it should arrive.

Comment: It works with another APNS client, but nodeJS module's payload didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218771/6135652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue with using another properties of nodeJS module like below:

```
notification.category = "MEETING_INVITATION";
notification.alert = {"title":"React with push","body":"Tap to see actions about that push."};
```

But the issue still exists for aps type payloads (content only):

```
notification.payload = {"aps":{"category":"MEETING_INVITATION","alert":{"title":"React with push","body":"Tap to see actions about that push."}}};
```

That's why, I left that node js module. I discovered some nice Mac AppStore APNS apps. One of them made a great job what I expected. Maybe we can resolve it with nodeJS too, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement this method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
  //do some data processing if needed
  completion(.alert)
}
```

Because UNUserNotificationCenter should handle such notifications, not AppDelegate. Please note what it is a part of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol. Hope this would help

Comment: Thank you for your support, but my problem stil exists. I have created local alert notification with actions, it's displaying but still don't work for remote payload. I have updated my question & AppDelegate.

Comment: Hm, good to hear that there is some progress. So, do you test push notifications on a real device? Do you specify correct APNs token?

Comment: It works with another APNS client, but nodeJS module's payload didn't work. stackoverflow.com/a/59218771/6135652